# Deployment of Minikube is failing on Mac Air 2020 with M1 chip

Tags: macos, kubernetes, lua

I have installed docker desktop and Minikube on my Mac Air 2020 with M1 chip successfully. I am trying to create a simple single cluster deployment "hello-node" by following the instructions on Kubernetes.io.[image]

When I run the

'''kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4'''

command, the pod does not move to ready state.When I check the kubectl logs deployment/hello-node I get the error:

'''[error] 1#1: failed to initialize Lua VM in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:54
nginx: [error] failed to initialize Lua VM in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:54'''

The issue seems to be the below warning, incompatibility of the platforms.

'''WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
2022/06/10 05:48:50 [error] 1#1: failed to initialize Lua VM in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:54
nginx: [error] failed to initialize Lua VM in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:54;'''
[image]

I have checked multiple venues but I could not find a solution around this. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the echoServer image does not have support for arm64 architecture. The issue was elevated as a candidate for minikube v1.23 but wasn't accepted. (now v1.27)

The "answer" per GitHub is to use this image, but I have had only limited success:
`gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/echoserver:2.2`

I recommend using this image instead: `polyverse/node-echo-server`

You can read more about this issue here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11107